# Same condition in C and Java but different Output

Tags: java, c

I'm doing pattern programming in C and java. I have written code for both the languages with same condition so i'm expecting the same output but i'm not getting same output.

Here is C code of pattern program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i,j;
  for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
  {
    for(j=1;j<=9;j++)
    {
      if(j<=(6-i)||j>=(4+i))
      printf("*");
      else
      printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
*********
**** ****
***   ***
**     **
*       *
```

Java Code:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
  int i,j;
  for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
  {
    for(j=1;j<=9;j++)
    {
      if(j<=(6-i)||j>=(4+i))
         System.out.print("*");
      else
       System.out.println();
  }
 }
}
}
```

Output:

```
*************
*******


*****




***






*
```

Help me to fix this problem

Comment: How did you debug, trace both implementations?

Answer (score 2):

The Java version prints a *new line* instead of a space like in the C version. Try this instead.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
      for(j=1;j<=9;j++)
      {
        if(j<=(6-i)||j>=(4+i))
          System.out.print("*");
        else
          System.out.print(" ");  // Prints space
      }
      System.out.println(); // Prints a newline for each row
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Java program you forget to write a line of code corresponding to `printf(" ");` in your C code. This in Java will be like `System.out.print(" ");`

Try this modified code :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {
                if (j <= (6 - i) || j >= (4 + i))
                    System.out.print("*");   // in C  printf("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");   // in C  printf(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();            // in C  printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
*********
**** ****
***   ***
**     **
*       *
```

Comment: Thank You. I got it